# Cross-compile to ARM64 (AARCH64) on Intel 64-bit Red Hat 7.5 can't find dlfcn.h, cstddef.h, etc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, arm

I have a program that compiles in gcc fine on Red Hat 64-bit Linux.  I run and it works perfectly fine to make a shared object file:

```
gcc -ansi -std=c++11-shared -fPIC...etc
```

I am trying to cross-compile for 64-bit ARM (AARCH64) on this same machine.

I installed the cross-compile tools:

```
sudo yum install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
sudo yum install gcc-c++-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

However, when I run the same command that works fine, just running as

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -ansi -std=c++11 -shared -fPIC...etc
```

It gets the errors and doesn't build:

```
 fatal error: dlfcn.h: No such file or directory
 #include <dlfcn.h>
```

If I comment that out, it hits the next includes of cstddef.h fatal error not found, etc

How do I make this work?

Comment: Sounds like you are missing glibc-headers.

Comment: It works for intel though - how do I set it up/install it differently for aarch64 on RHEL7.5?

Comment: Building with the host or target's headers?

Comment: You probably need `sudo yum install glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu` or something like it to get the standard library for aarch64.  Perhaps also something for the standard headers.

Comment: (for the target aarch64) That doesn't seem to exist in redhat 7.5, do you know the exact name?  Or what repo to pull this from, and then how to configure gcc/g++ with it?

Comment: @MaryEllenBench faced the exact same issue - finally just downloaded the rpm manually from [centos.pkgs.org](https://centos.pkgs.org)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem for a while and unfortunately I learned that developing on RedHat is not as easy as on Debian (at least for me). Finally I managed to install a cross compile toolchain for aarch64 and I'm using it now.
The version of redHat that I am using is : ***Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)*** and I downloaded the following packages for this release.

1. cross-gcc-common-4.8.5-16.el7.1.noarch.rpm
2. cross-binutils-common-2.27-9.el7.1.noarch.rpm
3. binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu-2.27-9.el7.1.x86_64.rpm
4. gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.8.5-16.el7.1.x86_64.rpm

Then install the packages in order with the command "`rpm -Uvh <package_name>.rpm`"(You most probably need sudo).

If everything goes well, you can try the command "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -v" to show version of aarch64 gcc.